# easiest way to host your node ftp server

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, ftp

I have been using heroku for my node js servers. This time I created an ftp server using ftp-srv npm package. However I have no idea how to host it. If I try to deploy it to heroku again, it provides me with an https url. I need to use ftp protocol, so need a url with ftp://. What could I do to deploy my server?